# Webfonts/@font-face: my Android 4.4.2 browser will only use SVG fonts and flicker on every page load (FOIT)

Tags: android, svg, fonts

I have some pretty weird problems in the Android browser on my Medion Lifetab S7852 (Android 4.4.2 - made by Lenovo as far as I know) when using self-hosted webfonts:

***Step 1:***

First of all, caniuse.com clearly states that the Android browser supports TTF since Android 2.2 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf) and WOFF since Android 4.4 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff). So using @font-face with the following syntax should work just fine (different font formats generated by Font Squirrel's generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)):

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:'daniel';
    src: url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

I implemented a demo of this here: http://www.sym-work.de/wf/example01

This works fine in the Android browser of my Samsung Galaxy S Advance (Android 2.3.6), the Android browser of my Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0.1), Chrome 44, Dolphin 11.4, Firefox 40 and Opera 30 on my Lifetab S7852 (Android 4.4.2), Safari on my iPhone 4S and my iPad 2 (both iOS 8.4.1) and in pretty much every single half-way up-to-date browser on Windows and Linux.

It will however **not** work in the Android 4.4.2 browser and Maxthon 4.5.1.2000 on my Lifetab (it seems Maxthon is basically just an alternate GUI for the system's Android browser?). It won't use the specified font and fall back to sans-serif.

What confuses me the most is that it works perfectly well on my stone age Android 2.3 phone, but not on Android 4.4 on a different device...

***Step 2:***

Adding an SVG font at the end, which according to all sources shouldn't be necessary:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:'daniel';
    src: url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.svg#danielregular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Demo here: http://www.sym-work.de/wf/example02

This kind of works - the font is rendered, however it suffers from heavy FOIT (Flash Of Invisible Text, "flickering") in the Android 4.4.2 browser. Every time I change the page through the menu on the left side, all the text is invisible for at least half a second (sometimes longer) on every load. I would expect that to happen when first loading the site, as it might take the browser some time to download the font, however after that it shouldn't happen again, as I expect the font file to be cached.

***Step 3:***

I alter the order of the font sources and put the SVG at the second position:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:'daniel';
    src: url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.svg#danielregular') format('svg'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../webfonts/daniel-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Demo here: http://www.sym-work.de/wf/example03

The font is rendered, no FOIT at all, the Android 4.4.2 browser pretty much behaves like all the other browsers.

However that's not an acceptable solution for me: The SVG's file size is significantly larger than the WOFF's and TTF's  -  I don't want to tell browsers (that (still) support SVG fonts) that their first choice should be downloading the largest file.

I thought it might have something to do with missing/wrong MIME types, so I added:

```
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/octet-stream .ttf
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
```

to an .htaccess for the Apache. No change at all.

Furthermore, all Google Font specimens I've tried (for example https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Poiret+One) won't work and just show the default sans-serif font.

What is going on here? Why does my Android 4.4.2 browser need SVG fonts? Why does SVG need to be on top of the source list to prevent heavy FOIT/flickering on every load? Could this be caused by some kind of weird Android implementation by Medion/Lenovo?

Can someone reproduce/confirm this problem on Android 4.4.2 (and/or 4.0/4.1/4.2/4.3)? It would also be very helpful telling me if you **don't** experience that problem and my first example works fine in the Android browser on your specific device, renders the font and doesn't flicker at all. I googled around a lot, but couldn't find anything helpful. Is this some weird bug that for some reason only I experience?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that 4.2's webfont implementation was severely broken, and rather than backport the fixes in 4.3 and 4.4, they just moved on, leaving 4.2 behind. On 4.2, something like http://pomax.github.io/CFF-glyphlet-fonts, may even show one webfont working, and the other not, *potentially switching which one works based on a page reload*. Android 4.2 is not very capable when it comes to webfonts.

Comment: This is Android **4.4.2**, so **4.4**, not **4.2**.